# Join results from multiple similar queries from same table but with different conditions

Tags: select, join, conditional-statements

I am completely new at SQL.

I need to get the results of this query:

```
Select
Date,
SUM(SumPrice) as Price1,
SUM(SumAmount) as Amount1,
SUM(SumPrice)/SUM(SumAmount) as AVGprice1

FROM [BiSandbox].[dbo].[database]
where Condition = '1'  
group by Date
```

To line up with the results of this query:

```
Select
Date,
SUM(SumPrice) as Price2,
SUM(SumAmount) as Amount2,
SUM(SumPrice)/SUM(SumAmount) as AVGprice2

FROM [BiSandbox].[dbo].[database]
where Condition = '2'  
group by Date
```

They should line up, seeing as they are grouped by a common Date column. I have not been able to google/ search for a solution, seeing as it is a pretty narrow question. What is the correct syntax to join these two result tables? Can I join three?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table into itself if needed like this:

```
SELET
d1.Date,
SUM(d1.SumPrice) as Price1,
SUM(d1.SumAmount) as Amount1,
SUM(d1.SumPrice)/SUM(d1.SumAmount) as AVGprice1
SUM(d2.SumPrice) as Price2,
SUM(d2.SumAmount) as Amount2,
SUM(d2.SumPrice)/SUM(d2.SumAmount) as AVGprice2
FROM [BiSandbox].[dbo].[database] d1
    -- or the primary key column you have instead of id
    INNER JOIN [BiSandbox].[dbo].[database] d2 on d1.id = d2.id
WHERE d1.Condition = '1'
AND d2.Condition = '2' -- this can be an OR if needed
GROUP BY d1.Date
```

If this answer is not satisfying please provide some more details.